# Proving Lemma 4 in Georgi's Lie Algebra in Particle Physics 2nd p 251

Tags: group-theory, lie-algebra

[image]

The lemma 4 is given in the above picture. My question is, how to verify linear dependence (20.15) for diagram (a)? I tried to extend the matrix for the simple root in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E6_%28mathematics%29)
[image]
$$
\left [\begin{matrix}
1&-1&0&0&0&0 \\
0&1&-1&0&0&0 \\
0&0&1&-1&0&0 \\
0&0&0&1&1&0 \\
-\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}&\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\\
0&0&0&1&-1&0 \\
\end{matrix}\right ]
$$

by adding 7 on top of 6 as

$$
\left [\begin{matrix}
1&-1&0&0&0&0&0 \\
0&1&-1&0&0&0&0 \\
0&0&1&-1&0&0&0 \\
0&0&0&1&1&0&0 \\
-\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}&\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}&0\\
0&0&0&1&-1&0&0 \\
x_1&x_2&x_3&x_4&x_5&x_6&x_7 
\end{matrix}\right ]
$$

since the angle between vectors 1 and 7, 4 and 7 are both zero. Therefore $x_1=x_2=0$. Since 2 and 7 are orthogonal. $x_3=0$. Since 3 and 7 are orthogonal. $x_4=0$. Since 4 and 7 are orthogonal. $x_5=0$. Since 5 and 7 are orthogonal. $x_6=0$. The vectors 6 and 7 have to be orthogonal, which is contradict with Dykin diagram.

My construction of matrix for simple roots seems to be wrong. How to verify the linear dependence correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below follows the proof which Howard Georgi seems to have in mind. Let us call the root vector(s) in the Dynkin diagram $(a)$ corresponding to

1. the single $3$-vertex for $\vec{\gamma}$,
2. the three $2$-vertices for $\vec{\beta}_1$, $\vec{\beta}_2$, $\vec{\beta}_3$,
3. and the three $1$-vertices for $\vec{\alpha}_1$, $\vec{\alpha}_2$, $\vec{\alpha}_3$.

Since they are all connected through single lines, all seven root vectors have the same length, say, $\gamma$. Moreover, the pairwise angles $\theta$ are given by

$$\cos(\theta)~=~\left\{\begin{array}{rl}-\frac{1}{2}&\text{if a connecting line,} \\ \\ 0 &\text{if no connecting line.} \end{array}\right. $$

Thus we calculate

$$\left( 3\vec{\gamma}+2 \sum_{i=1}^3\vec{\beta}_i +\sum_{i=1}^3\vec{\alpha}_i \right)^2$$
$$~=~9 \vec{\gamma}^2+4 \sum_{i=1}^3\vec{\beta}_i^2 +\sum_{i=1}^3\vec{\alpha}_i^2 +12 \vec{\gamma}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^3\vec{\beta}_i + 4\sum_{i=1}^3\vec{\beta}_i\cdot \vec{\alpha}_i$$
$$~=~\gamma^2\left(9+4\cdot 3+3+ 12\cdot3\cdot(-\frac{1}{2})+ 4\cdot3\cdot(-\frac{1}{2}) \right)~=~0.$$

Hence the seven root-vectors are linearly dependent, so that the Dynkin diagram $(a)$ cannot represent a (finite-dimensional, complex) simple Lie algebra.